# WordPress - How to hide header picture on all pages except homepage?

Tags: wordpress, css

I inserted an image in the header of my WordPress page. Since it's in the header it shows up on every page and post. I was wondering if there's a way that I can hide the image on all pages and posts except the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body:not(.home) header img {
  display: none;
}
```

This selects all images in the `header` element of all pages that don't have the `.home` class in the `body` tag and hides them.

Comment: Could you explain it in a detailed way? I don't get anything you said!

Comment: I inserted that code in my css but now it's removing the website logo as well

Comment: Then you should assign a class or an ID to the image you want to hide and use that instead of the `img` in the CSS selector: `body:not(.home) header .yourimageclass`. Concerning detailed explanation: It's a combined CSS selector. Read my above explanation word by word and compare it with the code - there is no other explanation. If you don't know much about (combined) CSS selectors, I recommend to google a tutorial about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please place the header image line inside the home page condition in the header, just like this:

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage
    <img src="<?php echo get_header_image() ; ?>" alt="<?php echo( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?>" />
 } 
 ?>
```

Hope, this may be helpful for you.

Comment: Prateek where should i place it? The theme header.php? Just as is?

Comment: Find this type of <img> tag in your header.php file

Comment: <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
      <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( get_custom_header()->attachment_id ) ); ?>" sizes="<?php echo esc_attr( $custom_header_sizes ); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
     </a>

Comment: There is no <img> tag in the header.php I manually added the image

Comment: If you had manually added the image, so just only place the if ( is_home() ) { condition before your manually added <img> tag, & it will be diaplayed only on home page.